More efficient iteration method
I m looking for a better way of doing the following. The code below works but its very slow because I m working with a large dataset. I was trying to also use itertools but somehow I couldnt make it work. So here my very unpythonic starting point.
Helper function:
def signalbin(x,y):
  if x > y:
      return 1
  else:
      return -1

Test Data:
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': np.random.normal(0, 2.5, n),
        'b': np.random.normal(0, 2.5, n),
    }
)

My Current code:
df["signal"] = [signalbin(x, y) for x, y in zip(df["a"], df["b"])]
df["signal2"] = df["signal"]
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i == 0:
        continue

    if (row['signal2'] != df.at[i-1, "signal"]):
        df.at[i, "signal2"] = df.at[i-1, "signal2"]

In this case the column signal2 is the desired result.
So I m looking for a more efficient iteration logic that allows to put conditions on multiple columns and rows

Is this the real function or a dummy example?

Usually, df.iterrows() is rather slow.

this is a dummy example, but the real function attempts the same just with more complex data and slightly more complex helper function

yes Jan, iterrows() is slow but somehow I cant find a faster way, hence the q

Is this what you're looking for? How can I iterate over rows in a Pandas DataFrame? It doesn't address this specific situation, but it covers strategies to use.

For more specifics, are these what you're looking for? Create Column with ELIF in Pandas (a little more complicated than necessary, but maybe your real function is more complicated to match, IDK) and Comparing previous row values in Pandas DataFrame

The first part will depend on your real function; it might not be easy to improve it.
The second part can be vectorized with shift, mask, and  ffill.
# vectorization of the dummy example
# this might not be possible with a more complex function
df['signal'] = np.where(df['a']>df['b'], 1, -1)

# get previous row
prev = df['signal'].shift(fill_value=df['signal'].iloc[0])

# identify changing values, mask , ffill
df['signal2'] = (df['signal'].mask(df['signal'].ne(prev)).ffill()
                 .astype(df['signal'].dtype) # optional
                )

Output:
          a         b  signal  signal2
0  4.410131  0.360109       1        1
1  1.000393  3.635684      -1        1
2  2.446845  1.902594       1        1
3  5.602233  0.304188       1        1
4  4.668895  1.109658       1        1
5 -2.443195  0.834186      -1        1
6  2.375221  3.735198      -1       -1
7 -0.378393 -0.512896       1       -1
8 -0.258047  0.782669      -1       -1
9  1.026496 -2.135239       1       -1

